# How to make a ProgressIndicator span inside a grid?

Tags: dynamic, grid-layouts, gui-construction, style, display

Setting `ImageSize -> Full` in the ProgressIndicator makes the indicator extend to fill up the width of the notebook. But I have one inside a grid, so how can I make it extend to the width of the grid? Here what it looks like:

[image]

Here is a simple example of how SpanFromLeft fails to accomplish what I need:

[image]

and the code to copy:

```
Grid[
  {
    {ToString@Range[1, 10], 2, 3}, 
    {ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[x], ImageSize -> Full], SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}, 
    {7, 8, 9}
  }, Frame -> All
]
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to generate that picture?

Comment: @MarcoB I added it, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = Grid[
      {{ToString@Range[1, 10], 2, 3}, 
       {"", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}, 
       {7, 8, 9}}, Frame -> All];
a /. 
 "" -> ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[x], ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[a // Rasterize][[1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to use `Rasterize`, but I think you are right it's the only way...

Comment: It's not that bad. You only need it to determine size. It's not that you're turning everything into coarse pixels now.